# Change status bar color - Navigation View

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm using `NavigationView` from design library. I wanted to try the following:

1. Change status bar color over NavigationView.
2. Update NavigationView to start below status bar.

(Both are different scenarios)

How I can achieve this ?

I already tried using `statusBarColor` and `colorPrimaryDark` attributes and it doesn't work for status bar above `NavigationView`

Answer (score 1):

You should add it to your styles.xml, for example :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your colors here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F5662</item> 
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3F5662</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you checking it on API 21 and above? this color change only works on lollipop and above